# Why using UseCookieAuthentication cause exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

asp.net 5 mvc 6, visual studio 2015 RC

Why is this code causes an exception when i run application in (debug/release)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
        options.AuthenticationType = "Cookies";
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Action/Login");
});
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Could not load file or assembly **Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILoggerFactory, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**  or one of their dependencies. Can not find the file specified.

My nugets packages:

```
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Security": "1.0.0-beta3",
"Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
"Npgsql": "2.2.5"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove Security packages and add this:

**"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4"**

and,  in login/register controller

```
var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Username)};            
Context.Response.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies")));
```

beta5 and forward:

```
var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Username)};            
await Context.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies")));
```

Comment: I tried this and it compiles but it doesn't seem to actually sign me in, actions protected with [Authorize] attribute still return a 401. Is this working for you?

Comment: app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            });

Comment: var claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, USERNAME)
                };

                Context.Response.SignIn("Cookies", new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies")));                                It's work for me.

Comment: I was missing options.AutomaticAuthentication = true; its working now, thanks

Comment: Does this bypass the login screen?

Comment: No, [Authorize] attr will redirect to "/Action/Login"

Comment: Interesting. It didn't redirect for me and it went straight into the application.